# How to return value after loadFinished in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a script, that works fine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    bot = GBot()
    bot.search('hot tea', num=20)
    if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

When I call search(), program starts working, and and loads website:

```
def _loadFinished(self, ok):
        current_url = self.page().currentFrame().url().toString()
        if str(current_url).endswith('.com/'):
            self.home_search()
        else:
            self.get_links_text_from_page()
            
        if self.count >= self.desired_number_of_results:
            self.close()
```

After load finished 1 time, it checks for another condition and desides what to do next.
At the end, after program loads multiple websites. Desired data collected in variable called `self.results`.

So my question is how I can return result from search(), by checking condition of loadFinished().

Another words, I need to come up with some sort of algorithm that will check if loadFinished will not load any other websites, and than `search()` function will return desired variable. I was thinking to create another variable `self.result = False` than change the condition in `loadFinished()` and in `search()` place everything in `while loop`, and after that `return` result. But it doesn't work...

## search()

```
def search(self, keyword, num=None, output=None):
    self.keyword = keyword
    if output is "json":
    # need to return `self.results` ONLY after program finished. because before that,
    # this variable is empty
    self.load('somewebsite.com')
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could use a generator here. In this `QWebView` example, `loadWebsites` is called until `StopIteration` is raised, in which case `procDone` is emitted with the number of loaded websites. The output for that signal is captured in the slot `on_procDone`. (The output in this case is `3`, because of `["http://www.example.com"]*3`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit, QtNetwork

class myWindow(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    procDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.websites      = iter(["http://www.example.com"]*3)
        self.websitesTotal = 0

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loadFinished)
        self.procDone.connect(self.on_procDone)

        self.loadWebsites()

    def loadWebsites(self):
        try:
            website = self.websites.next()

        except StopIteration:
            self.procDone.emit(self.websitesTotal)

        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(website))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_loadFinished(self, ok):
        self.websitesTotal += 1
        print "Loaded: {0}".format(self.url().toString())
        self.loadWebsites()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_procDone(self, total):
        print "Total of websites: {0}".format(total)
        self.websitesTotal = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. You right, creating custom SIGNAL will do this. Didn't think about it before.